# Deleting duplicate rows in "large" sqlite table takes too much time (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, orm, database-cursor

I have a relatively small sqlite3 database (~2.6GB) with 820k rows and 26 columns (single table). I run an iterative process, and every time new data is generated, the data is placed in a pandas dataframe, and inserted into the sqlite database with the function `insert_values_to_table`. This process operates fine and is very fast.

After every data insert, the database is sanitized from its duplicate row listings (all 26 columns need to be duplicate) with the function `sanitize_database`. This operation connects to the database in similar fashion, creates a cursor, and executes the following logic: Create new temporary_table with only unique values from original table --> Delete all rows from original table --> Insert all rows from temporary table into empty original table --> Drop the temporary table.

It works, but the `sanitize_database` function is extremely slow, and can easily take up to an hour for even this small dataset. I tried to set a certain column as primary key, or to unique value, however, [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) does not allow for this operation as it can either insert the whole dataframe at once, or none at all. That functionality can be reviewed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15988) (`append_skipdupes`).

Is there a method to make this process more efficient?

```
#Function to insert pandas dataframes into SQLITE3 database
def insert_values_to_table(table_name, output):
    conn = connect_to_db("/mnt/wwn-0x5002538e00000000-part1/DATABASE/table_name.db")

    #if connection exists perform data insertion
    if conn is not None:
        c = conn.cursor()        
        
        #Add pandas data (output) into sql database
        output.to_sql(name=table_name, con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)                

        #Close connection
        conn.close()
        print('SQL insert process finished')

#To keep only unique rows in SQLITE3 database
def sanitize_database():
    conn = connect_to_db("/mnt/wwn-0x5002538e00000000-part1/DATABASE/table_name.db")
    c = conn.cursor()   
    c.executescript(""" 
        CREATE TABLE temp_table as SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_name; 
        DELETE FROM table_name;
        INSERT INTO table_name SELECT * FROM temp_table;
        DROP TABLE temp_table
        """)
    conn.close()
```

Comment: have you tried to read the database using pandas, add the new data, remove duplicates then add again to the database?

Comment: No, from what I understood, executing operations in sql architecture *should* always be faster compared to loading the entire database into memory, making alterations, and writing it back, especially when the database grows in size?

Comment: If you want to operate on database side, why bother with pandas? `to_sql` is merely there for the purpose of putting data to the db. You should definitely work with some SQL library instead of trying to wrap said libraries by Pandas.

Comment: @Quang Hoang, you might be right, but the to_sql part is not the problematic part of my code, this is the sanitize database part which is written in SQL and performed database side.. Or are you implying I should find an alternative to to_sql to have primary key in my sql database?

Comment: Yes (alternative to `to_sql`) to either insert if key is not there, or update the record. our problem is *After every data insert, ...*, so essentially you copy/paste your entire schema after every insert, which is costly.

Comment: This would be very fast and easy if you try to do this inside the database itself. Because of DBMSs are optimized very well to increase performance. Where pandas don't have `that level` of optimization. And inside the sqlite, you can make this operation even faster by indexing (which makes it easier to search through entries). I suggest you to try to optimize the DBMS side. Not the python code in this case. Because of pandas doesn't support this kind of optimizations directly.